# How to show / hide all tags with the same class with Java Script?

Tags: javascript

I need a javascrit function that shows/hides all span tags with a specific class (t1, t2 or t3) in a HTML document. Example:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
    function sh(t){//show_hide(text number class)
       //???
    }
//-->
</script>

<div id='C'>
 <p>
  <span class="P">
   Normal allways visible text. 
   <span class="t1">Text 1</span> 
   <span class="t2">Text 2</span> 
   <span class="t3">Text 3</span> 
   Normal allways visible text.
  </span>
 </p>
 <p>
  <span class="P">
   Normal allways visible text. 
   <span class="t1">Text 1</span> 
   <span class="t2">Text 2</span> 
   <span class="t3">Text 3</span> 
   Normal (allways visible text.
  </span>
 </p>
 <p><span>Normal allways visible text.</span></p>
</div>
```

The function sh (show hide) could be trigerred like this:

```
<p>Show: <a href="#" onclick="sh('t1');">text 1</a> | <a href="#" onclick="sh(t2);">text 2</a> | <a href="#" onclick="sh(t3);">text 3</a></p>
```

**An important detail is that when the span class t1 is visible, all other span class t2 and t3 are hidden. The default is to have all span class t1 visible at the first load.**

Thanks a lot.

---

The folks have already got what I needed. There are two solutions:

Pure Javascript:
http://jsfiddle.net/4DREQ/

With the help of JQuery:
http://jsfiddle.net/v3vWM/3/

Comment: Without the comment by function sh(t) , I would have figured it does something else

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can modify the style definitions directly in javascript. It is a bit messy and you should check it on different browsers but it would look like this:

```
function findRule(selectorText)
{
    for(var i=0; i<document.styleSheets.length; i++)
    {
        // IE uses "rules", all other browsers use "cssRules".
        var rules = document.styleSheets[i].cssRules || document.styleSheets[i].rules;

        for(var j=0; j<rules.length; j++)
        {
            if(rules[j].selectorText == selectorText)
                return rules[j];
        }
    }
}
```

And then you can use something like:

```
findRule(".t1").style.backgroundColor = "Blue";
```

to change the definition of the style. This will reflect on all elements that use the css class "t1".

On the other hand, with jQuery you need only one line of code :-)

Comment: It even better for it doesn't need any extern library. I'll check if it is stable in other plataforms. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

As not all browsers support the all methods (e.g. IE does not support `getElementsByClassName`, I suggest to use a library like [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) that makes cross-browser DOM access very easy.

But luckily, `getElementsByTagName` is [supported by all browsers](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_core.html#t12), so you could do:

```
var spans = document.getElementsByTagName('span');

function sh(cls) {
    for (var i = spans.length; i--;) {
        var element = spans[i];
        if (element.className.match(RegExp('\\b' + cls + '\\b'))) {
            element.style.display = (element.style.display === 'none') ? '' : 'none';
        }
    }
}
```

I don't know which spans you want to hide or show, so I just assume you are going to toggle the visibility of one group. If you are going to get the span elements only once like I did, then you have to put the script *after* the content (before the closing `<body>` tag). Otherwise the span element won't be found.

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Xr7yM/)

---

If supported, using [`document.querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/document.querySelectorAll) might be even better. You could do:

```
window.sh = (function() {
    function toggleVisibility(element) {
        element.style.display = (element.style.display === 'none') ? '' : 'none';
    }

    if(typeof document.querySelectorAll === 'function') {
        return function(cls) {
            var spans = document.querySelectorAll('span.' + cls);
            for (var i = spans.length; i--;) {
                toggleVisibility(spans[i]);
            }
        };
    }
    else {
        var spans = document.getElementsByTagName('span');
        return function(cls) {
            for (var i = spans.length; i--;) {
                var element = spans[i];
                if (element.className.match(RegExp('\\b' + cls + '\\b'))) {
                    toggleVisibility(element);
                }
            }
       };
    } 
}());
```

This checks once whether `querySelectorAll` is supported creates an appropriate `sh` function.

[**DEMO 2**](http://jsfiddle.net/Xr7yM/2/)

Comment: Felix, please, the only thing is the when t1 is clicked, it must hide the others. Take a look: http://jsfiddle.net/v3vWM/

Comment: @Roger: Have a look at http://jsfiddle.net/v3vWM/3/ ... it is easier when you add a common class to all the elements. Is this what you want? Or only for `t1`? Have also a look at http://jsfiddle.net/v3vWM/4/

Comment: The example in http://jsfiddle.net/v3vWM/3/ is really what I am looking for. The only thing I need now is to find a way to let t1 visible (t2 and t3 hidden) for default.

Comment: @Roger: You can hide t2 and t3 initially with CSS. `.t2, .t3 {display: none}`

Answer (score 1):

jQuery solution: http://jsfiddle.net/tEUYC/

Updated solution: http://jsfiddle.net/tEUYC/1/

Updated again: http://jsfiddle.net/tEUYC/2/

Comment: Very good. The only thing is that when t1 is visible, all the others t2 and t3 are hidden...

Comment: I guess it fits like a glove now. Can you tell me how how to make t1 visible and all the others (t2 and t3 hidden) for the default load?

Comment: Well, I choose to hide them in the css declaration.

Comment: @Roger Yes, you can use CSS. Also, you can do it via jQuery. Just add `.first().click()` to the end of the existing code. I've updated my answer with this third demo.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend [jQuery](http://jquery.com). You can do this in a single line of code:

```
$(".t1").hide();
```

For your case it sounds like you also want to take a look at the "accordion" widget in jQueryUI.

Answer (score -1):

JQuery is simpler and uses less code. Download Jquery from here and include in your project http://docs.jquery.com/Downloading_jQuery